# android mediaplayer won't play

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i have an application where the first activity has a *start* button, when the button has been pressed, the second activity pop's up with something like a calculator. each time the number is pressed, a media sound would be played with the following code

```
if (mp != null) {
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    }
    mp = null;
}
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.c4_beep1);
mp.start();
```

now, when the user is done with the second activity, and press a button to go back to the first activity with

```
mTextView.setText("its over");
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DefuseMe.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_righ);
```

everything works fine here, but when I press *start* again from the first activity, the sounds stopped working.

**EDIT:**I put *finish()* there because i thought it would just kill the second activity and when i press *start* again it will start a new activity, and i thought everything would work just fine.

Comment: Are you keeping the above snippet of code in onCreate Method?

Answer (score 0):

I make this run successfully.My code is as followings:

1:ActivityOne:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp != null) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                }
                mp = null;
            }

           mp  = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.beep);
            mp.start();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

2:activity two:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two_layout);

    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SecondActivity.this.finish();

        }
    });
}
```

Everytime I start the second activity,The beep will start.